# Android bluetooth data across multiple devices at the same time

Tags: java, android, audio, bluetooth, audio-streaming

I want one Android device to be a "host" device that transmits streaming audio data to x amount of other devices that have connected to the host device.  I have an app that does this on iOS, but I'm unsure of how to approach this on Android.

Is it possible to stream audio from one device to x amount of other devices via bluetooth?
If so does Android have any built-in tools for transmitting data and connecting MULTIPLE bluetooth devices to each other?

As for the streaming, I imagine I would need to "packetize" the audio file and send it to the other devices.  Does Android have a tool for reading streaming data?

It would be nice if there are some libraries available for this type of work.